# Python: optimizing pairwise overlaps between intervals

Tags: python, intervals

I have a great amount of intervals (around 5k to 10k). These elements have a start and end position; like (203, 405). The coordinates of the intervals are stored in a list.

I want to determine the coordinates and lengths of the overlapping parts **between each pair** of intervals. This can be done as follows:

```
# a small list for clarity, with length normally around 5000s
cList = ((20, 54), (25, 48), (67, 133), (90,152), (140,211), (190,230)) 
for i, c1 in enumerate(cList[:-1]): # a linear pairwise combination
    for c2 in cList[i + 1:]:
        left =  max(c1[0], c2[0])
        right = min(c1[1], c2[1])
        overlap = right - left
        if overlap > 0:
            print "left: %s, right: %s, length: %s" % (left, right, overlap)
```

Resulting in:

```
left: 25, right: 48, length: 23
left: 90, right: 133, length: 43
left: 140, right: 152, length: 12
left: 190, right: 211, length: 21
```

As can be seen, it works... since this can take quite some time (20 seconds) my question is, how would I optimize this? I tried to cut off the second for loop when the start position of the second loop exceeds the first end position:

```
if c1[1] < c2[0]:
    break
```

This drastically decreases the procedure time, but the resulting number of overlaps is about three times less than before, and therefor the result is certainly not valid. This is caused by elements which are much greater in length than preceding elements.

I'm sure there is some mathematical trick to solve this issue

Comment: What if the list is `[(0, 4), (1, 5), (2, 6)]`, so you have a complex multi-overlap pattern? Do you still want pairwise overlap results? (In that case, the overlap intervals will themselves overlap.)

Comment: What if the list is `[(0, 4), (2, 6), (4, 8), (6, 10)]`? Do you want an output of `[(2, 4), (4, 6), (6, 8)]`, or `[(2, 8)]`, or something else?

Comment: This (genomic-)data surely contains multi-overlaps. But in my case it is only interesting to retrieve the pairwise overlaps. I understand what you mean with the overlapping overlaps. In the above example it might be a bit confusing. The real data consists of objects and not only coordinates...

Comment: I want the individual pairwise overlaps, so [(2,8)] wouldn't be correct.

Comment: @Benjamin please edit your question to mention that you want pairwise overlaps. As it reads, you seem to want segments where **all** regions overlap

Comment: if you're looking for information related to this kind of problems, what you called "elements" are generally called "intervals"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally, this kind of problem becomes much easier if you sort the intervals by starting point.

Firstly, let us define a function, in order to make things clearer:

```
def overlap( r1, r2 ):
    left =  max(r1[0], r2[0])
    right = min(r1[1], r2[1])
    over = right - left
    return (left, right, over) if over>0 else None
```

The algorithm you described can then be written as:

```
for i, c1 in enumerate(cList[:-1]): 
    for c2 in cList[i + 1:]:
        o = overlap(c1,c2)
        if not o is None:
            print "left: %s, right: %s, length: %s" % o
```

If you sort the elements, you can "short-circuit" as soon as you find a non-overlapping segment, since you know those further in the list will be even further "away":

```
l= sorted(cList)
for i, c1 in enumerate(l[:-1]): 
    for c2 in l[i + 1:]:
        o= overlap(c1,c2)
        if o is None:
            break
        print "left: %s, right: %s, length: %s" % o
```

Of course, if your input is already sorted (as it seems), you can skip that step.

Note that, in general, instead of using the double `for`, you can use the much clearer [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations). It guarantees the same kind of ordering. Unfortunately, it isn't suitable for the optimized version of the algorithm, but yours could be written as

```
from itertools import combinations
for c1,c2 in combinations(cList, 2):
    o= overlap(c1,c2)
    if not o is None:
        print "left: %s, right: %s, length: %s" % o
```

Finally, if you ever want to perform fast **generic operations** on intervals, you may also want to consider using a [Interval Tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree) data structure. There's [a python implementation on pypi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/interval_tree/0.1).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I the optimization I proposed first: `if c1[1] < c2[0]:
    break`
Gave the exact same result. But because of a very deep burried bug ,which caused the sorting to be manipulated, I was getting really strange results. But it works now! Thank you